# PSD and linear inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I am not sure why $Ax \succeq b$ can be thought of as a linear inequality constraint on some optimization problem? $Ax \succeq b$ seems to mean that $Ax - b \succeq 0$. A is of shape (n, d), b is of shape (d, 1), b is of shape(n, 1), $\succeq$ is the PSD sign.

Comment: What do these symbols mean?  Is $A$ a matrix of some sort?  What does $\succeq$ mean?

Comment: @Tony If $Ax$ and $b$ are not square matrices, then using $\succeq$ doesn't make sense.  Presumably, the author simply means that each entry of $Ax$ is greater than or equal to the corresponding entry of $b$, i.e. $Ax \geq b$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, thanks, I got the idea.(forget this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When applied to square matrices, $\text{LHS} \succeq \text{RHS}$ means that  $\text{LHS} - \text{RHS}$  is symmetric PSD.

Some authors, perhaps afflicted with Semidefinite Programming Syndrome (SDPS), choose to also use $\succeq$ when applied to vectors, as in $Ax \succeq b$, in which case it just means $Ax \ge b$, i.e., a standard, element-wise inequality. I am not defending this practice, just explaining it.